# Mic port not working by default, and with pactl a different physical jack is enabled each time

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

Microphone jack doesn't work after boot by default. After some trial and error, I learned that:

```bash
pactl load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,2
# and sometimes
pactl load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:2,2
```

will create a new source which is my mic jack, however it's assigned to a different physical port each time, meaning sometimes it's rear mic, rear line-in, and sometimes it's front mic.

What's happening?

Posted question on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484448/pactl-source-module-assigns-a-random-port-for-mic-each-time) as well.

specs:

- linux 6.2.0-32-generic
- ubuntu 22.04 lts, pactl 15.99.1
- motherboard: z690-e,
- audio: 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7ad0 (rev 11)